# Java reference conditional expression

Tags: java

```
// This is my test code
int i = a == 1? c = 3: d = 4; // error message

// And when the Intellij rewrite it in form of if clause
int i;
if (a == 1) i = c = 3 = 4;
else i = d = 4;

// Another code
int i = a == 1? (c = 3): (d = 4); // work

// If clause
int i;
if (a == 1) i = c = 3;
else i = d = 4;
```

Can someone explain what happen in each cases? Why do we need parenthesis surround expression 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to [Operator Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

The ternary operator `?:` has higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`. Which means that `a == 1 ? c = 3: d` is evaluated first and then `= 4`.

That statement would be equal to `int i = (a == 1 ? c = 3 : d) = 4;`. Which is not valid java though, as you can't assign a value to a value.

You solved the problem already by using parentheses `()`, which indicate (like in normal maths) that everything in them should be evaluated first.